# Cannot assign left side - Boolean(RecBuf[0]) := false

Tags: delphi

I'm converting an old code from Delphi 5 to XE5.
It has this piece of code:

```
Boolean(RecBuf[0]) := False;
```

RecBuf is PChar. 
This works in Delphi 7, but not in XE5.
In XE5, it gives "Left side cannot assign" error.
How to implement this code in XE5?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Delphi 7, `PChar` is an alias for `PAnsiChar`. That is, pointer to 8 bit ANSI character. Which means that `RecBuf[0]` has type `AnsiChar`. Since `AnsiChar` and `Boolean` have the same size, the cast is valid.

In Delphi XE5, `PChar` is an alias for `PWideChar`, pointer to 16 bit wide character. And so `RecBuf[0]` has type `WideChar`. Thus the cast is invalid because `WideChar` and `Boolean` have different size.

Exactly how best to fix the problem cannot be discerned from the code that you have shown here. Quite possibly you need to redeclare `RecBuf`. Perhaps it needs to be declared as `PAnsiChar`. Although one does wonder why you are casting a character to a `Boolean`.

Another possibility is that the reason `RecBuf` is declared as `PChar` is to allow you to use the index operator `[]`, something that in older versions of Delphi is a special capability of pointers to character types. In modern Delphi you can use `{$POINTERMATH ON}` to enable that functionality for all typed pointers. So, if you did that then perhaps `RecBuf` should be `PBoolean`.

The bottom line is that whilst we can explain why the compiler complains about your code, we cannot give you a definitive solution.

Answer (score -1):

Judging from RecBuf name they are used not as a pointer to string but as a pointer to buffer allocated in memory.

If my assumption correct, you may want to redeclare RecBuf as a variable of type PByte.

Comment: Why PByte rather than PBoolean?

Comment: PChar is often used for buffer definition just because they support pointer arithmetic while other pointer types in Delphi version < 2009 not.

After changing PChar from PAnsiChar to PWideChar delphi manual suggest use PByte instead: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Enabling_Applications_for_Unicode#Use_of_PChar_Casts_to_Enable_Pointer_Arithmetic

If RecBuf always point to records with same structure it may be worth to define record type and declare RecBuf as a pointer to record type instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can't assign cast stuff on the left, you need to cast the right side.

Instead of

```
Newtype(Whatever) := NewtypeConstant;
```

you should use

```
Whatever := TUnknown(constant)
```

In yourcase, of recbuf is an array of say, byte, then it puts false (0) in it, so it should be

```
Recbuf[0] := Byte(False);
```

Or you could, you know, just put zero in there.

Comment: Not so. You can cast the left hand value of an assignment. You cannot neglect the Ansi/Wide character difference.